# React Native ListView Items not displaying

Tags: javascript, listview, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to use the React Native `<ListView />` component with the `<List />` and `<ListItem />` component from React Native Elements but the `<ListItem />` component isn't displaying. Not entirely sure why. Shouldn't my `renderRow` function be running for every object in my array and returning `<Listitem />`? My data is coming in fine.

[image]

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks! Code is below

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text, ListView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { List, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements'
import { getMakeData } from '~/redux/modules/data'

class Make extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        makeData: PropTypes.array.isRequired
    }
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 })
        this.state = {
            dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.makeData)
        }
    }
    componentDidMount () {
        this.props.dispatch(getMakeData())
    }
    renderRow = (item) => {
        return (
            <ListItem
                key={item.id}
                title={item.name}
            />
        )
    }
    render () {
        console.log(this.props.makeData)
        return (
            <List style={{flex: 1}}>
                <ListView 
                    renderRow={item => this.renderRow(item)}
                    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                />
            </List>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps ({data}) {
    return {
        makeData: data.makeData
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Make)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

})
```

Comment: can you put `console.log(this.props.makeData)` inside `render` method and show the output ??

Comment: @MayankShukla Yeah looks like `componentDidMount` isn't running because i'm getting an empty array as the output of `console.log(this.props.makeData)` the error is firing before anything in my component gets to run. I also get an error `Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'dataSource' of type 'Array' supplied to 'ListView', expected instance of 'ListViewDataSource'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your issue is you are not using `renderRow` correctly. Based on your description, `makeData` is an array of objects, so in your `render` function, you call `ListView` with that array, but `renderRow` should only render single row and should be passed in the data for each row. So, change your `renderRow` and `render` function like below

```
renderRow (item) {
    return (
        <ListItem
            key={item.id}
            title={item.name}
        />
    )
}
render () {
    return (
        <List style={{flex: 1}}>
            <ListView 
                renderRow={(item) => this.renderRow(item)}
                dataSource={this.props.makeData}
            />
        </List>
    )
}
```

What is happening now is that you are telling `renderRow` here is the object you should be using.

What you had before is you are trying to render `ListItem` using the array `makeData`, where you should be using a single object to render the row.

Comment: Ok I've fixed the issue w/ the error but now I'm not able get the the `<ListItem />` component to display. I've updated the code.

Comment: Look at how I rendered ListView. You need to pass in the item to this.renderRow

Answer (score 0):

fix bug:
`renderRow={this.renderRowt}` -> `renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}`

refactor code

```
function mapStateToProps ({ data }) {
    return {
        makeData: data.makeData
    }
}
```

->

1-

```
function mapStateToProps ({ data:{makeData} }) {
        return {
            makeData,
        }
    }
    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Make)
```

2-

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ data:{makeData} }) => makeData
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Make)
```

3-

```
export default connect(({ data:{makeData} }) => makeData)(Make)
```